# Android RuntimeError: Unable to find explicit activity class BUT i did not call that class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I encountered an error when I was running my application on an emulator. 
Here's the Error:

*Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.fyp.e_attendance/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?*

HOWEVER, I guess I have already created an activity called 'Menu' in the manifest and I did not call for 
any activity by the name of 'android.view.Menu'. I am stuck, please help me.

**Here's my manifest code:**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fyp.e_attendance"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
<!--         android:debuggable="true"> -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Menu" />
        <activity android:name=".ScanAttendance" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here's my .java code:**

```
package com.fyp.e_attendance;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

        //menu list
        ListView optionList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        optionList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        optionList.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main_menu, OPTIONS));

    }

    static final String[] OPTIONS = new String[] {
        "Scan for Attendance",
        "Mark Attendance manually",
        "View Attendance"
    };  

//public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
//  if (position == 0){
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanAttendance.class);
//      startActivity(intent);
//  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace

Comment: I cant post pic yet because this is a new acc without reputation..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the Intent creation (you didn't post that code). I think that you created the intent in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
```

but in at the beginning you likely imported: `android.view.Menu` instead of using `com.fyp.e_attendance.Menu`

Comment: THANK YOU! Yea, i think I accidentally imported that using the shortcut keys so I didnt realise. I got it solved~ Thank you so much!